# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in has_one association in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've checked numerous posts here and applied dozens of answers without success. So here it is... kept it simple... including using simple_form.

In my User model I have:

```
has_one :instrument
accepts_nested_attributes_for :instrument
attr_accessible ... :instrument_attributes
```

In my Instrument model I have:

```
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :user_id, :do_inst1, :do_inst2, :do_inst3, :do_inst4
```

In my UsersController I have:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_instrument
end

def create_user
  @user = User.new(params[:user]) # <== THE LINE PRODUCING THE ERROR

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "User created successfully."}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

In my new user _form.html.erb I have:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for :user, url: create_user_users_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :instrument do |instrument_f| %>
        <%= instrument_f.check_box :do_inst1 %>
        <%= instrument_f.check_box :do_inst2 %>
        <%= instrument_f.check_box :do_inst3 %>
        <%= instrument_f.check_box :do_inst4 %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Register User" %>
<% end %>
```

Error Msg: 
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: instrument
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:51:in `new'
Line 51 is indicated above by, "# <== THE LINE PRODUCING THE ERROR"

Comment: Can you post definition of `@user.build_do_instrument`.

Comment: What's the attribute you are having problem with? Can you post the error?

Comment: To make it less confusing, I changed "do_instrument" to "instrument" in all but 1 place. Sorry.

Comment: Added error msg at the end of the post. Thanks.

Comment: `f.fields_for :do_instrument` doesn't look write.  You should reference the form by its model name.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using

```
<%= f.fields_for :do_instrument do |instrument_f| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.fields_for :instrument do |instrument_f| %>
```

you can always inspect your incoming params to detect the source of the error. You can write this in your respective controller method and see the terminal for output.

```
puts "*"*30
puts params
puts "*"*30
```

This is simplest way of diagnosing the problem, otherwise you can use different gems available for debugging.

Comment: Yes... you are right. I was trying to simplify the syntax by changing "do_instrument" to "instrument" but I missed a couple. I am sorry.